# How can I debug this python code?

Tags: python

I am trying to use a [python wrapper](http://datadesk.github.io/python-documentcloud/) to post to an API.

When I step into the following code from the library in pycharm

```
    # Make the request
    self._make_request(
        self.BASE_URI + method,
        params.encode("utf-8"),
    )
```

it jumps to this retry method

```
def retry(ExceptionToCheck, tries=3, delay=2, backoff=2):
    """
    Retry decorator published by Saltry Crane.

    http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/trying-out-retry-decorator-python/
    """
```

I think that it jumps there because of the following decorator in _make_request (altho I do not understand Python decorators yet):

```
@retry(Exception, tries=3)
def _make_request(self, url, params=None, opener=None):
```

However, I am at a dead end because if I set breakpoints in @retry and look at the ExceptionToCheck it just shows a blank BaseException with no message and no args.

Does this code somehow skip the _make_request method (this is what the step into implies in pycharm) or does it somehow just jump to @retry.

What are the next steps that I can take to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep stepping - `retry` is applied as a wrapper around `_make_request`, it will eventually call that code.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator *wraps* a function. That means, when you call a function that has a decorator, the decorator function is called instead. But the decorator function will then (usually) in turn call the decorated one. So, you need to keep stepping through `retry` until you get to the bit where it calls the original function. Since the original was a parameter to the decorator, you'll probably see something like `return func(*args)` or whatever.